# Web forms data entry generator for SQLite

Tags: android, asp.net, sqlite, web-applications, data-entry

I'm building an android application that is very data intensive, and need to an interface to use to add data quickly and easily.

i've looked at all of the database tools, none of which make it easy to enter data using foreign keys.  I need all the foreign key fields to show up with dropdown lists (for 1-1) or checkbox lists (for *-1) for fields to make it easy to enter data.

The closest I've found to achieving this is the following:
  http://www.sqlmaestro.com/products/sqlite/datawizard/download/

Which claims to generate ASP.Net forms from a database.  Does anybody know any other tools that'd help me?

I guess I could build my own forms,but would prefer to spend my time developing my app. I'd be happy with a framework to kickstart development of my required forms, maybe somebody has done something similar already?  (ASP.Net preferable but not a necessity).

Answer (score 1):

I know the aspnet maker.

http://www.hkvstore.com/aspnetmaker/

Can create very fast a full site that handle your database manipulations. 
Its not free, and you stick with what ever he gives you, but is not that bad for quick tool.

From the other, do you ever hear the **scaffold** ?

I have use the SubSonic ver 2, that have scaffold, but other DAL have also.
What this technique do is to automatic create the editing forms for your.

you can search on google for "scaffold asp.net"

So you can select a DAL that have scaffold and use that.

Comment: Thanks... yeah there's also Microsoft's Dynamic Data Scaffolding product, however it wont generate foreign keys.  I think i might just have to code this myself (or try that Maestro product, that might do the trick).